# Why is Visual Studio Code altering my Angular html?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have the following segment of code in my Angular html:

```
<div class="col">
<input 
   #changeValue
   type="range" 
   min={{minMaxPrices.minPrice}} 
   max={{minMaxPrices.maxPrice}}     
   classname="custom-range w-100"        
   (change)="handlePriceChange(changeValue.value)"
/>
```

Within the code is the template variable #changeValue. But whenever I save the code in in Visual Studio Code the template variable, #changeValue is automatically assigned to itself like so: #changeValue="#changeValue" as shown below.

```
<div class="col">
<input 
   #changeValue="#changeValue" 
   type="range" 
   min={{minMaxPrices.minPrice}} 
   max={{minMaxPrices.maxPrice}}     
   classname="custom-range w-100"        
   (change)="handlePriceChange(changeValue.value)"
/>
```

And this breaks my code. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: open the settings and go to the setings.json file. I think there you could find the line something like this `"editor.formatOnSave": true,`. change it to `false` or just remove it. I will clarify, If I will know what OS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any VS Code extensions for auto-code formatting enabled? That could be the cause.

To disable auto-format, you can add `"editor.formatOnSave": false` to your [settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).